# How to send array result in mail using meteor javascript

Tags: meteor

I am beginner for Meteor Javascript. I am trying to send mail array result. and my code as below

```
 var Testname = test.find({}).fetch();
var a = [];
    var b = [];
    var c = [];
    var allResult = [];
    _.each(Testname, function(testname){
            var testResult = test.findOne({_id:testname._id});
            var st = testResult.st;
            var end_date = testResult.et;
            var pt = testResult.percentileCalculationTill;

            var br = testAttempts.find({activity_id:testname._id,start_time:{$st, $pt}}).count();
            b.push(br);

            var Afterresult = testAttempts.find({activity_id:testname._id,start_time:{$pt, $lt:end_date}}).count();
            a.push(Afterresult);

            var k = testname.name;
            c.push(k);


        });
var email = {
        to: 'xxx.com',          
        from: 'xxxx.com',
        subject: "xxx",
        cc: "xxx",
        text: "Name: " + c + 
        "\n\nWith : " + b + 
        "\n\nAfter: " + a
        }; 


Meteor.call("send_email", email.to, email.from, email.subject, email.cc, email.text);
```

My result sending as

```
Name : abs, dfg
With: 4,5
After: 7,6
```

But i want as below `

```
Name : abs    With: 4     After: 7
Name : dfg    With: 5    After: 6`
```

So How can i solve it.
Please update me soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have three arrays: a, b, c, which are all equal length. You need to loop through the arrays and combine the corresponding elements piece by piece. The below code is not the best solution (for example, you really shouldn't use a.length to determine the length of a,b,c) but it is the easiest approach to understand and should point you in the right direction.

```
var textString = '';
for(var row = 0; row < a.length; row++){
    textString = textString + 'Name: ' + c[row] + ' With: ' + b[row] + ' After: ' + a[row] + '\n\n'
}

var email = {
    to: 'xxx.com',          
    from: 'xxxx.com',
    subject: "xxx",
    cc: "xxx",
    text: textString
    };
```

Comment: And other thing is can we use an html tags for Name:..., with:.....and for After: ....?????

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean about html tags, but if you change the inside part of the for loop, you can make the string whatever you want to. Yes, I think using html tags in that string will be fine, but I have never tried to use html in email